# How to get gloss to not close ghci?

Tags: opengl, haskell, glut, ghci, gloss

[`gloss`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss) is a nice library for graphics. The problem, is, when I run it in `ghci`, it closes `ghci` as soon as I exit. I tried using `forkIO`, but it still closes ghci after closing the window. How do I get `gloss` to not close ghci (or at least keep the history) or is it better to just use a file?

Comment: confirmed for ghc-7.8.4, gloss-1.9.2.1, with xmonad, for running the example given on the API docs web page.

Answer (score 0):

As the web site suggests (http://gloss.ouroborus.net/)

```
A2: Try installing gloss to use the GLFW window manager 
interface instead of GLUT: cabal install gloss --flags="GLFW -GLUT"
```

I could get this to work with ghc-7.6.3 (after pressing ESC in the window, I'm back to ghci)

but I cannot compile this for ghc-7.8.4 (because cabal complains)

```
next goal: GLFW-b (dependency of gloss-1.9.2.1:+glfw)
rejecting: GLFW-b-1.4.7.2, 1.4.7.1, 1.4.7, 1.4.6, 1.4.5, 1.4.4, 1.4.3, 1.4.2,
1.4.1, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2.1, 1.2.0, 1.1.0, 1.0.2, 1.0.1, 1.0.0, 0.1.0.5, 0.1.0.4,
0.1.0.3, 0.1.0.2, 0.1.0.1, 0.1.0.0, 0.0.2.10, 0.0.2.9, 0.0.2.8, 0.0.2.7,
0.0.2.6, 0.0.2.5, 0.0.2.4, 0.0.2.3, 0.0.2.2, 0.0.2.1, 0.0.2, 0.0.1 (conflict:
gloss-1.9.2.1:glfw => GLFW-b>=0.1.4.1 && <0.2)
```